# libxml2 C library: SAX push parser context: xmlParseChunk error when passed null terminated string

Tags: c, xml, parsing, sax, libxml2

I have created an `xmlParserCtxtPtr` with libxml2's `xmlCreatePushParserCtxt`, passing a pointer to a custom `xmlSAXHandler` in the process.

I then read a line from an XML document file stream into a character buffer, replacing the end of line character with a `\0` null termination character.

This `chars` buffer is then being passed as follows:

```
xmlParseChunk(pParserCtxt, chars, numChars, 0);
```

`numChars` is the number of characters from the start of the buffer, up to and including the null termination character.

My issue is that none of the SAX handlers are being called, and the `xmlParseChunk` function is returning the following enumerated error (47):

```
XML_ERR_PI_NOT_FINISHED
```

This occurs for every chunk that is passed in the chars buffer, but I believe the parser is stuck in an error state from the initial null terminated string that it processed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

As the documentation for the libxml2 library is sparse, as are its inline comments, I was hoping someone with more experience with the library could point out my error?

Thank you for taking a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not pass NUL characters to `xmlParseChunk`. Simply pass chunks without a terminating character. There's a `size` parameter to pass the length of a chunk.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look @newllnhof. I am now stripping out every character from the file stream that is not explicitly part of a valid XML token (i.e. element start tag, element end tag, empty element tag, and element text).

However, despite the `char *` buffer looking correct in the debugger (only containing the expected chunk, up to the index specified), the parser is throwing error `73` (`XML_ERR_GT_REQUIRED`).

All I can think of is that the UTF-8 encoding is not compatible with `getc`, or `libxml` is reading more of the buffer than the size specified (which contains junk characters).

Comment: This is what is contained in the buffer:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<gameConfig xmlns:x0="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">\n  <acto`. The length of the chunk passed to `libxml` is 38. The error thrown indicates that a `>` character was expected, and is missing. However, the 38th character is a `>`.

Comment: I can tell from the SAX callback invocation that the parser is reading beyond the 38 character limit set in the `xmlParseChunk` parameters. The .startElement callback is being triggered, for an element named `gameConfig`. The error must be being thrown when the incomplete token, at the end of junk characters in the buffer, is being parsed.

Comment: Actually, I tried flush the junk characters from the buffer before reading in the XML chunk, and I still got a lone `.startElement` callback for a `gameConfig` element. I think I must be initialising my parser context incorrectly, such that it is caching a chunk before I expect it to.

Comment: Do you pass an initial chunk with `xmlCreatePushParserCtxt`? If yes, then make sure you don't pass it twice to `xmlParseChunk`. It would also be helpful if you could post a reduced test case.

Comment: Thanks @nwellnhof, I came to the same conclusion. After reading the `libxml` source code, I can see that `xmlCreatePushParserCtxt` does not just use the initialisation XML chunk to determine encoding, but also pushes it to its internal buffer. This malformed chunk was being processed entirely upon the first `xmlParseChunk` call, even though a new, valid chunk was being passed to the function. I now initialise the context without the chunk, and it is working as expected. Thank you for your help.